# Trying to do n applications of a function

Tags: python-3.x

Appreciate you looking at this.  As title suggests, I am trying to get the nth application of a function.

The first implementation works, however, the second implementation does not.  Could someone point me to the reason why?  I am using Python 3.4 if that makes a difference.

First implementation:

```
def repeated(f,n):
    def value(x):
        k=n
        while k>=1:
            x=f(x)
            k=k-1
        return x
    return value
```

Second implementation:

```
def repeated1(f,n):
    def value(x):
        while n>=1:
            x=f(x)
            n=n-1
        return x
    return value
```

Error is local variable n is referenced before assignment…This seems off to me as n is defined in the parent function.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a left fold applying the function f - [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366374/what-is-the-pythonic-equivalent-to-the-fold-function-from-functional-program)?

Answer (score 1):

Python, by default, allows *access* to variables from enclosing scopes, but does *not* allow you to set them—the minute you try to set one, Python considers it a local variable, and all accesses within that function to point to that local variable.

If you really want to, you can tell Python you really *do* want to set a non-local variable. To do this, use the `nonlocal` keyword. This works similarly to the `global` keyword:

```
def spam(var):
    def eggs():
        nonlocal var
        var += 1
        return var

    return eggs
```

In your case, though, this might be undesirable; you don’t want `f` to be invoked `n` times on the first invocation of the repeated-application function and no times at all on subsequent calls. For this reason, your first implementation is probably what you want.

---

As a general comment on your code, while it does not exhibit such interesting behavior, I would write this using a `for` loop:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    def value(x):
        for k in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x

    return value
```