# Building disjunction automatically

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I have to build disjunctive/conjunctive formula automatically, all I know is the length of list from where I have to acquire the values of variables, e.g:

```
x=Int('x')    
list= [0,1,2,3]
solver=Solver()
```

one approach to do this manually:

```
solver.add(Or(x==0,x==1,x==2,x==3))
```

Is it possible to load values of x from a list automatically within a loop or any list comprehension approach? as all I know is the len(list).

Comment: I suppose the list is also accessible so that you can get the elements? I think Python's reduce operator should do the trick nicely in functional style, see e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366374/what-is-the-pythonic-equivalent-to-the-fold-function-from-functional-program

Comment: lambda and reduce functions do evaluate the result as true of false, whereas I am interested to write disjunction automatically, I dont want reduce to evaluate it.I just want to bring it into this form...
    Or(x==0,x==1,x==2,x==3)
as my goal is to pass it to z3.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you would like to do. What is the problem with using a standard 'for i in ...' loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe that the `z3.Or` takes in a tuple, so we can just use the python constructs to build that.

```
solver.add(Or(tuple([x == obj for obj in list])))
```