# Spark Scala Dataframe How to create new column with two or more existing columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a Spark Scala DataFrame object like:

`+----------------+
|col1  |col2     |
+----------------+
|1     |2        |
|3     |4        |
+----------------+`

And I want a DataFrame like:

`+--------------------+
|col1  |col2  |col3  |
+--------------------+
|1     |2     |3     |
|3     |4     |7     |
+--------------------+`

Which adds `col1` and `col2` to `col3`, could anyone please tell me how to do that? `WithColumn` takes only one column as parameter whereas I need to take two columns.

Comment: Consider that `withColumn` is lazy and will be optimized at runtime, I'm fairly sure you can call it twice for the two columns without any problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a column of rowsums across a list of columns in Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624699/adding-a-column-of-rowsums-across-a-list-of-columns-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `withColumn` or `select` as

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,2),
  (3,4)
).toDF("col1", "col2")

df.withColumn("col3", $"col1" + $"col2").show(false)

df.select($"col1", $"col2", ($"col1" + $"col2").as("col3")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |
|3   |4   |7   |
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

WithColumn takes two parameters a name and a function that should result in a type column - so a function or expression whose result is a column is valid hence you can do the below (or similar)

```
df.withColumn("col3", df("col1")+df("col2"))
```