# Java Spark Sql add column with sum of 2 cells

Tags: apache-spark-sql

given a dataset with 2 columns:

```
| col1 | col2 | 
|   1  |  2   |
|   2  |  2   |
|   1  |  2   |
|   1  |  2   |
```

I would like to add a column with the sum of col1 and col2

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|   1  |  2   |  3   |
|   2  |  2   |  4   |
|   1  |  2   |  3   |
|   1  |  2   |  3   |
```

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624699/adding-a-column-of-rowsums-across-a-list-of-columns-in-spark-dataframe) which basically seems to do exactly the same but in Scala.
Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is present in `df`, the desired output can be obtained by using either of the below mentioned ways,

1. Using Dataframe operations

```
df.select("col1", "col2", (df3.col1 + df3.col2).alias("col3")).show()
```

2. Using Spark SQL

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_data")
spark.sql("select *, (col1 + col2) as col3 from temp_data").show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   2|   2|   4|
|   1|   2|   3|
|   1|   2|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below answer to create a new column in df.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("new col", col("col1") + col("col2"))
df1.show
```