# How to implement auto increment in spark SQL(PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement a auto increment column in my spark sql table, how could i do that. Kindly guide me. i am using pyspark 2.0

Thank you 
Kalyan

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955309/add-column-sum-as-new-column-in-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: @MRSrinivas thanks for your detailed reply i will try it, recently i have tried 
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id for solving the problem it has worked . It gives ids for every row indexing from 0 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write/reuse **stateful Hive udf** and register with pySpark as Spark SQL does have good support for Hive.

check this line `@UDFType(deterministic = false, stateful = true)` in below code to make sure it's stateful UDF.

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;

/**
 * UDFRowSequence.
 */
@Description(name = "row_sequence",
    value = "_FUNC_() - Returns a generated row sequence number starting from 1")
@UDFType(deterministic = false, stateful = true)
public class UDFRowSequence extends UDF
{
  private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();

  public UDFRowSequence() {
    result.set(0);
  }

  public LongWritable evaluate() {
    result.set(result.get() + 1);
    return result;
  }
}

// End UDFRowSequence.java
```

Now build the jar and add the location when pyspark get's started.

```
$ pyspark --jars your_jar_name.jar
```

Then register with `sqlContext`.

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION row_seq AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence'")
```

Now use `row_seq()` in select query

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT row_seq(), col1, col2 FROM table_name")
```

[Project to use Hive UDFs in pySpark](https://github.com/bmc/spark-hive-udf)

Comment: I have built the jar as you have specified and created the temporary functions as well. Now I created a table `sqlContext.sql("Create table abc(id int, name string)")` and `sqlContext.sql("INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT row_seq(), 'John'")` and `sqlContext.sql("INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT row_seq(), 'Tim'")`. When I do select * statement I am getting both `iD` as `1` instead of `1` and `2`.

Comment: Are setting `stateful = true` inside tag `@UDFType` in your code?

Comment: I need something like this but the question is, Will it scale with data of 200 millions. Actually I want to break a big file containing 200 millions rows in smaller files of exact 10K rows containing file. I thought to add auto-increment number for each row and read in batch with the help of like this (id >10,001 and id < 20,000). Will this work at that scale, please suggest.

Comment: is it possible to do this UDF in python? and register it in sqlContext as well?