# python reduce accum as an argument

Tags: python, reduce

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366374/what-is-the-pythonic-equivalent-to-the-fold-function-from-functional-program) thread in SO, `reduce` is equivalent to fold. However, in Haskell, accum parameter is also passed to fold. What is the way in python to pass accumulator in `reduce`.

```
my_func(accum, list_elem):
     if list_elem > 5:
       return accum and True # or just accum
     return accum and False # or just False

reduce(my_func, my_list)
```

Here, I want to pass `True` as accumulator. What is the way in python to pass initial accumulator value.

Comment: [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) accepts the accumulator as a third parameter

Comment: Thanks. I hope I missed it. It seems an answer.

Comment: I was not able to understand as many examples do not use third parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), `reduce` accepts an optional third parameter as the accumulation initializer.

You can write:

```
def my_func(acc, elem):
    return acc and elem > 5

reduce(my_func, my_list, True)
```

or, using a lambda:

```
reduce(lambda a,e: a and e > 5, my_list, True)
```

---

Alternatively, for this particular example, where you want to check that 5 is strictly lower than *all* the elements in `my_list`, you can use

```
greater_than_five = (5).__lt__
all(greater_than_five, my_list)
```