# How could one reduce the usage of helper functions in lambda expressions?

Tags: python, data-structures, lambda, functional-programming, one-liner

In this example I'm taking letters from a set and append them to a dictionary where the letter becomes the key and the literal 1 becomes the value to each pair.

```
def base_dict_from_set(s):
    return reduce(lambda d,e : addvalue(1, e, d), s, dict())


def addvalue(value, key, d):
    d[key] = value
    return d
```

```
>>> base_dict_from_set(set("Hello World!".lower()))
{'o': 1, '!': 1, 'l': 1, 'd': 1, 'w': 1, ' ': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1, 'h': 1}
```

I was wondering whether I could somehow be rid of the 'addvalue' helper function and add the element and reference the modified dictionary within the lambda function itself.

The routine within addvalue itself seams very simple to me, so I would prefer something that looks like this:

```
def base_dict_from_set(s):
    reutrn reduce(lambda d,e : d[e] = 1, s, dict())
```

I don't have a lot of experience in python and I come from a functional programming perspective. My goal is to understand pythons functional capabilities but I am too unexperienced to properly phrase and google what I am looking for.

Comment: I love that the question title has the word "reduce" in it.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is why `dict.fromkeys` exists: create a dict that maps each key to the same constant value.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys("Hello World!".lower(), 1)
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, ' ': 1, 'w': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1, '!': 1}
```

There's no need to convert the string to a `set` first, since any duplicates will just be overwritten by the following occurrences.

(If the constant value is mutable, you should use the dict comprehension to ensure that each key gets its *own* mutable value, rather than every key sharing a reference to the same mutable value.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the same result:

```
{l: 1 for l in set("Hello World!".lower())}
```

Comment: Only if they don't want to really count occurrences

Comment: *"the literal 1 becomes the value"* — Yeah, sounds like they don't.

Comment: Frankly, none of us knows what the OP is really trying to do. I think it's great that we came up with several different answers.

Answer (score 3):

To answer exactly the question asked, yes you can get rid of the `addvalue` by replacing `addvalue(1, e, d)` with `{**d, e:1}`.

Nevertheless, your code is still faulty. It is not counting the occurrences, but creates a dict of `key: 1` for every letter in the string and it should create a dict of `key: number_of_occurences` to achieve this you should replace `addvalue(1, e, d)` with `{**d, e: 1 + (d[e] if e in d else 0)}` and not convert the string to `set` as it eliminates duplicates

Comment: Don't worry about that flaw; it is, as stupid as it might sound, in fact very much on purpose. Your solution is definetly very nice though and I thank you for taking your time! :)

Comment: You shouldn't call your functions in a manner indicating they do something they do not :)

Comment: @Nez Now I'm curious. What *is* your purpose?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn yeah you are right. Might be a bit misleading. I was curious where I could look up the syntax you introduced, I have no idea what I am looking at

Comment: @Stef Really it's only for learning python. I'm looking for fun ways to implement an algorithm which finds a unique letter for each word in a list. Part of it is counting occurences of letters in the words in general, ignoring doubles though. Did this in Haskell before so my approach might seam a bit odd (and I loooove folds/reduce)

Comment: @Nez [very short python doc on `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and also [Question about unpacking and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking)

Comment: @Nez If you want to transform a sentence into a list of words, you will be interested in [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

Comment: @Nez also note that python is a terrible language for functional programming; solutions with iteration (and possibly [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)) are usually preferred.

Comment: @Nez Don't look if you don't want spoilers, but would this solve your problem: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@7bsMwDEV3fQW3SECRJUtQwFM/wzAMR5YbtTKpUFReP@/KdRxkaLcrQudcMt7kSLjbR54mP0ZiAUshOCueMCnVuwEGj32b0Z@ya@2x4zY6bi/EvU4OxaF15l1B4XJ5cYIK6hfH9mOZ65kwMBDDnMAjrPg2xeBFm6ZYhKQLRZHyqFfjGyTpWKq/rMYUiJ1kRqjRXUXb3w47FzwE4Ic11raBqlpaSl72eX57EqlRKrJH0f8fvzllb7/hwHTBornCVx5jAjoXU@juN@jpc2PMNP0A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Stef are you saying python is terrible in a sense that code becomes unreadable or are you also referring to perfomance issues?
For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366417/15813942

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised that you tried to use `reduce` when your goal is to transform each item in an input collection (the letters in a string) to an output collection (a key/value pair where the key is the letter and the value is a constant number), independently of each other.

In my view, `reduce` is for when an operation needs to be done to items in a sequence and taking all previous items into account (for instance, when calculating a sum of values).

So in a functional style, using `map` here would be more appropriate than `reduce`, in my opinion. Python supports this:

```
def quant_dict_from_set(s):
    return dict(map(lambda c: (c, 1), s.lower()))
```

Where `map` converts the string to key/value pairs and the `dict` constructor collects these pairs in a dictionary, while eliminating duplicate keys at the same time.

But more idiomatic approaches would be to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132326) or the [`dict.fromkeys` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132409).

Comment: Using `reduce` would make sense if he really wanted to count occurences

Answer (score 1):

Hacky and hard to read, but closest to the `lambda` you were trying to write, and hopefully educational:

```
>>> f = lambda d, e: d.__setitem__(e, 1) or d
>>> d = {}
>>> output = f(d, 42)
>>> output
{42: 1}
>>> output is d
True
```

Using `__setitem__` avoids the `=` assignment.

`__setitem__` returns `None`, so the expression `d.__setitem__(e, 1) or d` always evaluates to `d`, which is returned by the `lambda`.

Comment: Oof, IMO the better way to achieve this is in my answer

Comment: @Vulwsztyn the code in my answer should not be used. It's purely educational.

Comment: I mean `d.__setitem__(e, 1) or d` is equivalent to `{**d, e: 1}`

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Ah, I see. Yep, that's clever!

Comment: That's the natural approach for someone coming from JS background, :)

Comment: @Vulwsztyn however, the answers are not strictly equivalent. Your solution returns a **new** dictionary, mine mutates the input dictionary.

Comment: So, my approach is even more functional than yours :D

Comment: Very educational indeed! I wasn't even aware of the 'or' keyword. @Vulwsztyn why would you say returning new dictionaries is more functional then modifying the already existing one. Are you concerned about insufficient buffer size?

Comment: Modifying anything is not a functional approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), a subclass of `dict` specifically for counting occurrences of elements.

```py
>>> import collections

>>> collections.Counter('Hello, World!'.lower())
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, ',': 1, ' ': 1, 'w': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1, '!': 1})

>>> collections.Counter(set('Hello, World!'.lower()))
Counter({'w': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 1, ',': 1, 'h': 1, 'd': 1, 'o': 1, 'e': 1, ' ': 1, '!': 1})
```

Note that `Counter` is appropriate if you want to count the elements, of if you want to initiate the values to the constant 1. If you want to initiate the values to another constant, then Counter will not be the solution and you should use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132326) or the [`dict.fromkeys` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132409).

Comment: The OP isn't counting the elements, only using a constant-valued `dict` as a replacement for the set.

Comment: @chepner isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: There's a (subtle) difference between setting a constant value and counting things you already know to be distinct.

Comment: @chepner Obviously that difference is so subtle that I'm not seeing it. Could you explain it please?

Comment: Change the first argument of `addvalue` from 1 to literally anything else.